# Update Drush 6.0.2. to v. 7 or 8

Tags: drush

So I have some Drupal Webportals based on the Drupal 7.x version.
I also have on mine server, Drush installed.

When I do on Drush an version check. It's show's me that I have version 6.0.2.
How can I upgrade/update to the version 7 or 8 of Drush?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you do simple research online? [How to Upgrade Drush](https://www.drupal.org/node/901828)

Comment: Yes.................